# Why don't all DC motors spontaneously melt down when given no voltage?

Tags: power, dc-motor

When I look at the power equation:

$$ P = IV $$

This suggests that if I reduce the voltage by half it would double the current. In general the current draw should be:

$$ \frac{P}{V}$$

So if I evaluate this with voltage going to 0:

$$ \lim_{v \rightarrow  0} \frac{P}{V}  \rightarrow \infty $$

So a motor with no voltage potential at its terminals really ought to be drawing close to infinite current/maximum current available to draw.

Obviously we don't see that in real life so that makes me wonder, why is that? Is it truly because when motors have 0 V potential difference then whatever they are drawing from is by definition depleted implying there can be no current draw?

Does that also mean I can rapidly discharge a "low voltage" battery by attaching it to a motor/makes such a motor melt down?

Comment: Heh... It takes, well, work, to enforce a condition like constant power. Almost all the time, power is the dependent variable, and so unpowered things simply dissipate zero power, because they have resistance and \$P = V^2/R\$. :)

Comment: It's not well known that DC motors take *a tremendous amount of current* at start-up. The stall current is simply a much higher current than the no-load running current. It's not a tremendous amount, like a 1 A motor pulling 80 A.

Comment: "tremendous" = stall current sorry about that.

Comment: Resistance exists.

Comment: when supply voltage is reduced, then the motor current is also reduced ... lower voltage is not able to push as much current through the motor

Comment: Your limit is incorrect. Since  Power is a function of the voltage across the motor, your limit is basically 0/0 which is indeterminate without more information. That information is that P=IV so your limit becomes I which goes to zero as V goes to zero since the motor has some non-zero impedance.. No infinite values here.

Comment: Why do you think power should be constant? It's not.

Comment: But \$P=IV\$, therefore \$\frac{P}{V}=\frac{IV}{V}=I\$, which goes to zero as \$V\rightarrow 0\$, since \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$

Comment: @Barry, the limit part there isn't wrong there, really. The assumptions just before are way off.

Answer (score 2):

You're ignoring Ohm's Law. The motor has resistance as well, and it takes voltage to produce current through that resistance.

$$I=\frac{E}{R}$$

Thus the current can only increase as voltage increases. Power is the ***product*** of voltage and current, but that's not the whole story; the other critical aspect is the load's resistance or impedance. In other words, you can't apply a voltage to a load, halve it and get a perfectly linear doubling of current **unless** that load is trying to consume a constant amount of power, as certain types of devices or a programmable load in that mode might do. But such devices have physical limits on how much power they can effectively use or dissipate.

Ignoring the fact that impedance and resistance changes with temperature and other factors, if the motor has a resistance of 10 Ω, applying 10 V will draw 1 A. If you then halve the voltage, the current (5/10) drops to 0.5 A. The *consumed* amount of power is 10 W in the first case and 5 W in the second.

<sup>*I use **E** for voltage in Ohm's Law instead of V.*</sup>